# how to get the list of process

Tags: node.js

I am playing around with node and just installed it on my machine. Now I want to get a list of processes running on my machine so I can see whether Apache is running, MySQL is started, etc? How can I do that? I just have very basic code in my js file. I don't even know where to begin on this.

Here is my code:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(request, response){
    response.writeHead(200);
    response.write("Hello world");
    console.log('Listenning on port 1339');
    response.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: windows, but would be good if you have something for windows and linux

Comment: https://github.com/viatropos/parse-processes/blob/master/index.js

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't a module (yet) to do this cross-platform. You can use the child process API to launch tools that will give the data you want. For Windows, just launch the built-in tasklist process.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('tasklist', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
  // stdout is a string containing the output of the command.
  // parse it and look for the apache and mysql processes.
});
```

Comment: I really like this method, it's much faster and uses less memory than other node modules I've tried. Do you know the mac/linux equivalent to tasklist?

Comment: @d_scalzi yes, in Linux the equivalent is ps -aux or with grep to find a certain program....   ps -aux | grep string

Comment: the is a platform independent module for this, it's silly to use a command line tool - see other answers here

Comment: This is giving me whole table in the form of string. How can query in that?

Answer (score 11):

[ps-list](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ps-list) is a better node package for the job, it is working on Linux, BSD, and Windows platforms too.

```
const psList = require('ps-list');

psList().then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    //=> [{pid: 3213, name: 'node', cmd: 'node test.js', cpu: '0.1'}, ...] 
});
```

Comment: Doesn't support a bunch of fields though - only the basics.

Comment: You may also want to filter out the `name === 'fastlist...'` process which is the process that collects the data for this plugin. (win10).

Answer (score 10):

See [ps-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ps-node)

To get a list of processes in node:

```
var ps = require('ps-node');

ps.lookup({
command: 'node',
arguments: '--debug',
}, function(err, resultList ) {
if (err) {
    throw new Error( err );
}

resultList.forEach(function( process ){
    if( process ){

        console.log( 'PID: %s, COMMAND: %s, ARGUMENTS: %s', process.pid, process.command, process.arguments );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: FYI: the arguments function looks for processes started with those arguments. For eg, "node myScript.js --debug"

Comment: The selected answer on this page explains the basic concept behind ps. Adding support for other operating systems looks relatively easy. https://github.com/neekey/ps/blob/master/lib/index.js

Comment: I just want to point out that ps-node is unreliable and should never be used in production or where you are relying it seriously. Why? It has known issues parsing the process listing table. This is *unpredictable* (i.e. it depends on what processes are running) and has bit me in the behind more than once. You have been warned.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use current-processes which lists all the processes.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/current-processes

The result includes **name**,**pid**,**cpu** and **memory** used by process.
You can also sort the result and limit the number of processes.
The result looks like this:

```
 [ Process {
pid: 31834,
name: 'atom',
cpu: 84,
mem: { private: 19942400, virtual: 2048, usage: 0.4810941724241514 } }]
```

Answer (score 3):

**Solution for unix-like systems:**

```
const child_process = require('child_process');

const displayProcessBy = (pattern) => {
    let command = `ps -aux | grep ${pattern}`;
    child_process.exec(command, (err, stdout, stdin) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(stdout);
    });
}
```

**Examples usage and results**

> displayProcessBy("nodejs");

```
setivol+  7912  0.0  0.0  12732  2108 ?        S    10:56   0:00 grep nodejs
setivol+ 12427  0.0  0.0 669552   712 pts/3    Tl   Dec16   0:00 nodejs
setivol+ 14400  0.0  0.0 669552   644 pts/2    Tl   Dec15   0:00 nodejs
setivol+ 14412  0.0  0.0 670576   224 pts/3    Tl   Dec16   0:00 nodejs
setivol+ 14567  0.0  0.0 669552   436 pts/3    Tl   Dec15   0:00 nodejs
setivol+ 14911  0.0  0.0 669552     0 pts/3    Tl   Dec15   0:00 nodejs
setivol+ 15489  0.0  0.0 669552   712 pts/3    Tl   Dec16   0:00 nodejs
setivol+ 15659  0.0  0.0 669520     0 pts/3    Tl   Dec16   0:00 nodejs --harmony
setivol+ 16469  0.0  0.0 669520   704 pts/3    Tl   Dec16   0:00 nodejs --harmony
setivol+ 20514  0.0  0.0 669552   664 pts/2    Tl   Dec15   0:00 nodejs
```

> displayProcessBy("python2")

```
setivol+  8012  0.0  0.0   4336   712 ?        S    10:58   0:00 /bin/sh -c ps -aux | grep python2
setivol+  8014  0.0  0.0  12728  2240 ?        S    10:58   0:00 grep python2
```

**Testing environment**

```
$ uname -a
Linux localhost 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux   
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.6 (jessie)
Release:    8.6
Codename:   jessie
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the **command line** tools rather than node scripts.

```
ps -aef | grep node
```

This would list the visual studio code helpers and .nvm env processes. We can **exclude** them using

```
ps -aef | grep node | grep -v "Visual Studio" | grep -v ".nvm"
```

Additional tip to **kill** all the listed processes:

```
killall node
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems there isn't any direct methods

but below videos might help.

- Monitoring Long Running Processes with Node. (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zamGXhjim00)
- CPU usage in real time with node.js & socket.io (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bPYgx9V6qAk)