# Node.js get pid at port

Tags: node.js, process, port, pid, kill

In Node.js, I want to kill a server running on port `1337`. `process.kill(pid)` seems like the way to do that. But how do I *get* the pid of the server running on port `1337`, in Node.js?

I see plenty of examples of how to do this with `ps` and `lsof`. Is there a way to pull this off without relying on shell commands in Node.js?

Here is how I would do this by relying on `lsof`:

```
Number(child_process.execSync('lsof -i :1337 -t'))
```

Comment: Have you launched the server process as a child from another nodejs process?

Comment: @Cuz Yes, and in my case that process has now exited.

Answer (score 2):

To answer my question, I can determine the pid(s) at a port with the `port-pid` package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/port-pid

However, to solve my problem, I instead adopted the philosophy that there was a "good reason" the port was in use, and instead opted to kill the child process from where it was spawned by wrapping `require('child_process').spawn`:

```
var childProcess = require('child_process');
var spawn = (function () {
  var children = [];
  process.on('exit', function () {
    children.forEach(function (child) {
      child.kill();
    });
  });
  return function () {
    var child = childProcess.spawn.apply(childProcess, arguments);
    children.push(child);
    return child;
  };
}());
spawn('node', ['server/server.js'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you launched the server as a child from another nodejs process, you can just do `child.pid` to get the pid of the server process.

Example:

```
var child = child_process.spawnSync(command[, args][, options]);
console.log(child.pid);
process.kill(child.pid);
```

Comment: In my case, the process which originally spawned `node` has exited. i.e., I do not have a `child` object representing the server that I want to kill.

Comment: I understand, in this case i don't think you can do without shell commands. You could try with ps-node as also stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206724/how-to-get-the-list-of-process) in the second answer. But i suggest you to refactor your code a bit to avoid this case, or to use some tool as programmatic pm2.