# Listen events of a process using pid

Tags: javascript, node.js, pid, child-process, forever-monitor

Think of having an admin app which creates & manages child apps.

I m spawning another child_process ( using `childProcess.spawn('node', 'somefile.js')` ). And, I m able to set event listeners (for ex, `exit`) on the childProcess, so that I can log the output & will know on child app exit.

But when the admin app restarts, I want to listen for the events on the child process again, so that adminapp will know the child app is crashed.

But `child_process` module doesn't have any method to get the childProcess instance by '**pid**' (or some other mechanism).

Can someone give pointers how to do this? Can we do this using [forever-monitor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever-monitor) or [pm2-api](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-api/)?

**Update**:
Code I've to spawn the child process:

```
let userWorkProcess = childProcess.spawn('node', [ 'someapp.js' ],
    {
        detached: true, 
        stdio: [ 'ignore', logFile, logFile ], 
        cwd: __dirname + '/someapp'
    }
);
userWorkProcess.unref();
userWorkProcess.on('exit', function () {
    if (userWorkProcess.exitCode !== 0) {
        // child process exited with some error
    } else {
        // child process exited without any error
    }
});
```

**Update #2**:

Can we connect to the process? For example, I see some code like that in forever-monitor. Is it possible using socket/nssocket?

https://github.com/foreverjs/forever/blob/master/lib/forever.js#L199
https://github.com/foreverjs/forever/blob/master/lib/forever.js#L229

Comment: Is it close http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206724/how-to-get-the-list-of-process ?

Comment: Can you specify how the child processes are open? e.g. via IPC or simple pipe (i.e. only have access to stdio)

Comment: @Rayon: I don't think so as I need to hook the event listeners, not just knowing the process details. Thanks.