# How can I figure out system load with express.js/node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I am creating a basic system monitoring utility as a practice exercise, and I am wondering if there a library I can use with express.js through which I can find out how many processes are currently utilizing the CPU?

I am on Windows 7 but would ideally like to be OS-agnostic. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure express is related to your task?  It's a networking package, while finding information about processes (system load) relates to the host. 
 Either way, inside your express route(s) you could insert the required code for finding the system load.

As stated in a response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206724/how-to-get-the-list-of-process),

> As far as I know there isn't a module (yet) to do this cross-platform.
>   You can use the child process API to launch tools that will give the
>   data you want. For Windows, just launch the built-in tasklist process.

They then include code to `exec` a child process via `require('child_process').exec` for acquiring task information.

Another answer to the same question shares the [ps-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ps-node) package.  I haven't worked with this package, but it appears to work similar to `exec`ing OS specific code.  It appears to have separate methods for Linux and Windows, meaning it may be simpler to pursue the OS-specific child-exec option.

Comment: That question actually basically has exactly what I need, or close enough for now. Not sure if it's cross-platform but it works on Windows at least. As for the involvement of express.js, the system-monitoring utility is intended to be opened as a web-app, communicating with an express.js backend. So I just needed to be sure that whatever utility I used was something node could run, and therefore something express could run.