# How can I get running processes count in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

**Scenario:**

1. I have a server which is accessed by multiple users. Server for ex: http://127.0.0.1:8081
2. It has one button and by clicking on it, it runs one selenium automated test.
3. I want to get a list of tests currently running by multiple users.

So for ex: if 5 users are accessing that server and clicked on that button 2 times it means that automated tests running are 10.

How can I get above count in node.js express like how many processes are running?

My server.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.send(
    '<form action="/server" method="POST">' +
    '  <input type="submit" name="server" value="Run Script" />' +
    '</form>');
});

app.post('/server', function (req, res) {
  var fork = require('child_process').fork;
  var child = fork('./test');
  res.send('Test Started....');

});

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port

   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
```

Comment: Just keep a count, when you create with `fork` increase counter,. when your `child.on('close'` is fired, decrease counter.

Comment: @Keith - Can I have example code please. That would help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but the following should do something like what your after.

Not sure were you wanted to access counter, so done another route  `/counter` that echo the current counter out.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var counter = 0;


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.send(
    '<form action="/server" method="POST">' +
    '  <input type="submit" name="server" value="Run Script" />' +
    '</form>');
});

app.get('/counter', function (req, res) {
  res.end("Counter = " + counter);
});

app.post('/server', function (req, res) {
  var fork = require('child_process').fork;
  var child = fork('./test');
  counter ++;
  child.on("close", function () { counter --; });
  res.send('Test Started....');
});

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port

   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain global count for clicked button.

```
global.total_tests = 0; // note this line
var express = require('express');
var app = express();


app.post('/server', function (req, res) {
    var fork = require('child_process').fork;
    var child = fork('./test');
    res.send('Test Started....');
    total_tests++; // note this line
});
```

I hope this help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [ps-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ps-node) as suggested in [this earlier Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206724/how-to-get-the-list-of-process).