# How to get information of currently running other windows/ mac applications from election.js?

Tags: electron

I am working on one application in which I want to get the information of other windows/mac application which are currently up and running. I also want to get their cpu usage. Is there any way to get this from electron?

Comment: Probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206724/how-to-get-the-list-of-process

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get the list of process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206724/how-to-get-the-list-of-process)