# JavaScript: How get an access to the system windows in OS Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, native

How can I get an access to the windows of programs with whom user work right now?

And this should not violate the security of the system.
The thing is that I want to write an application on NodeJS and Electron that can see which program is running and being used by the user.

Which one methods can I do that? Can I use a Windows API and how if the answer is 'yes'?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206724/how-to-get-the-list-of-process

Comment: @Dragonthoughts — The question isn't asking for help debugging code. It is asking how to get started with a problem. Asking for a [mcve] doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Quentin Showing some effort to start, is helpful, rather than just requesting someone else to write the code for an answer. Stack Overflow is a question and answer forum, not a free code writing service.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts — This isn't some kind of algorithmic exercise. It isn't something one can simply "attempt". I agree that there should be some effort demonstrated, but that would be very unlikely to take the form of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know electron so well, but in node.js, you have these types of options:

1. You can find an NPM module that knows how to list out the processes running on the current computer, install that module and use its API.  For example, here's one called [`process-list`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/process-list).  There are a bunch of others shown [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=npm%20windows%20process%20list&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS515US515&oq=npm%20windows%20process%20list&aqs=chrome..69i57j33.6167j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).
2. You can find a regular Windows command line program (similar to the Unix `ps`) that can list the current Windows processes at a command line prompt and you can then use the `child_process` module in node.js to run that program from node.js and capture its output.
3. You can write your own node.js native code plugin that accesses the Windows API directly to get this process information and then return that via the plugin to your Javascript.  This is likely what the NPM module in option #1 already did.

> Can I use a Windows API

Yes, from a native code plugin or via some plug-in that proxies access to the Windows API for you.  Windows API access is not directly built into node.js.

---

Personally I would stand on the shoulders of those who have already done this work and choose from the many NPM modules that appear to have this process listing functionality already built in.  Note: in any modern OS, there are security limitations to what you can do or learn about another process without having elevated privileges.  You can generally find out what's running.