# Get a list of process in VS Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

Is it possible to get a list of process that a debugger can be attached to? When selecting a processID using `"${command:pickProcess}`, you would get a list of .exe files that the debugger can attach to.

Is there a VS Code method in the VS Code API that would do the same thing in typescript?

I just want a list of all possible executables that can be attached to a debugger so that I can filter them out in a separate function.

Comment: I don't think VSCode API covers that, but Node.js has tons of packages https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206724/how-to-get-the-list-of-process/28466511

Comment: Is there any way to get the source code for the command in `${command:pickProcess}`?